# Make two Protocol methods exclusive (implement one or the other, not both)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let's say I have defined a protocol for a subclassed `UIView` as follows:

```
@protocol MyCustomViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (NSString*) titleForItemAtIndex;

- (UIImage*) imageForItemAtIndex;

@end
```

I would want the class implementing the delegate methods to implement only one, and not both the delegate methods. If the delegate implements `titleForItemAtIndex`, it must **NOT** implement `imageForItemAtIndex`, and vice versa. The compiler must throw a warning (or some other way to communicate to this to the programmer) if both methods are implemented by the delegate class. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask if the the delegate instance responds to a specific selector:

```
    if ([self.delegate respondToSelector:@selector(titleForItemAtIndex)]) {
        NSString * title = [title titleForItemAtIndex];
    }
    else if ([self.delegate respondToSelector:@selector(imageForItemAtIndex)]) {
        UIImage * title = [title imageForItemAtIndex];

    }
```

This will also require that you mark your delegate methods as `@optional` in the protocol declaration. With this condition you guarantee that the first method has the precedence on the second.
You can add one more `else` and throw an exception if none of them is called.

Comment: Thanks Andrea. This seems the best possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its possible to throw compiler errors. But still exceptions can be raised at runtime. You can use `NSAssert` and make sure that only one method is implemented at run time. This does not throw a compiler error but causes the app to crash with a log saying that only one method should be implemented.

```
// Checks for titleForItemAtIndex
if ([self.delegate respondToSelector:@selector(titleForItemAtIndex)])
{
    // Delegate has implemented titleForItemAtIndex.
    // So it should not be implementing imageForItemAtIndex
    // Below assert will check this
    NSAssert(![self.delegate respondToSelector:@selector(imageForItemAtIndex)], @"Delegate must not respond to imageForItemAtIndex");
    // Now that condition is checked. Do anything else as needed below.
}

// Checks for imageForItemAtIndex
if ([self.delegate respondToSelector:@selector(imageForItemAtIndex)]) {
    // Delegate has implemented imageForItemAtIndex.
    // So it should not be implementing titleForItemAtIndex
    // Below assert will check this
    NSAssert(![self.delegate respondToSelector:@selector(titleForItemAtIndex)], @"Delegate must not respond to titleForItemAtIndex");
    // Now that condition is checked. Do anything else as needed below.
}
```

Another approach would be to create separate protocols for both methods, and use the same `if assert` condition but with [`conformsToProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/conformsToProtocol:) If you have a lot of mutually exclusive methods, its better to create separate protocols.